# Where is the most recent version of the Kundera tutorial?

Tags: xml, cassandra, kundera

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes

I used that tutorial and the persistence.xml file does not compile or work in Eclipse. I get an "invalid xml" error instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try with latest 2.0.6 release. IT should work for you.

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes link has been updated for the same

-Vivek